# Image cannot be located when referenced in other UWP project

Tags: uwp

We wish to share visual assets between two UWP projects in a solution. The visual assets are in a UWP class library which is also in the same solution.

We can deploy a project when the visual assets are included in the same project by referencing them in `Package.appxmanifest` like this

`Assets\SplashScreen1240x600.png`

but if we try to reference visual assets in the class library like this

`OtherProect.Assets\SplashScreen1240x600.png`

we get this error

`the splash screen image [SplashScreen1240x600.png] cannot be located`.

How do we reference visual assets that are in a class library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reference UWP class library which is also in the same solution. if you want to reference visual assets in the class library please write your path like the following.

```
OtherProect\Assets\SplashScreen1240x600.png
```